# Warum kommt dieses Verb an der ersten Stelle des Satzes?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

> Warum die Regierung einschritt und welche Erfolgsbeispiele nach dem Zweiten Weltkrieg in der Alternativgeld-Szene für Furore sorgten, darum geht es in Kapitel 4 »Die Freigeldtheorie im Praxistest« und in Kapitel 5 »Regionalgeld – die heute erfolgreichsten Modelle«. Gefolgt von der Idee, Zeit wie Geld zu entlohnen. Micheal Linton gilt **da** als Erfinder der Tauschring-Bewegung. **Gegründet** hatte er den ersten LETS 1983 zur Bewältigung und Abfederung hoher Arbeitslosigkeit **auf** Vancouver Island, Kanada. Der Erfolg war groß, das System wurde weltweit vielfach kopiert.
>   <sub>*[Quelle](https://www.m-vg.de/mediafiles/article/pdfdemo/978-3-89879-858-7.pdf), Seite 19*</sub>

1. Warum kommt das Verb *»gegründet«* an der ersten Stelle des Satz, müsste es nicht am Ende sein?
2. Was meint *»da«* hier in diesem Zusammenhang?
3. Warum verwendet der Autor *»auf«* hier statt *»im«* ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### 1. Verb im Vorfeld.

Die erste Position im Satz heißt *»Vorfeld«*. Dort können viele Satzglieder stehen, besonders häufig findet man das Subjekt dort:

> *Das Haus* steht am Fluss.

Aber auch erlaubt sind:

- Dativobjekt

  > *Dem Tüchtigen* gehört die Welt.
- Akkusativobjekt

  > *Den Hasen* hat der Jäger erschossen.
- Präpositionalobjekt

  > *Auf besseres Wetter* warten wir schon lange.
- adverbiale Bestimmung

  > *An der Wand* hängt noch kein einziges Bild.
- Frageadverb

  > *Warum* bist du zu spät gekommen?
- Fragepronomen

  > *Wer* weiß die Antwort?

Aber man kann dort auch Teile des Prädikats platzieren:

- Prädikativ

  > *Ärztin* ist sie von Beruf.
- Infinitiv

  > *Trinken* solltest du dort nichts.
- Partizip II

  > *Gegründet* hatte er den ersten LETS 1983 zur Bewältigung und Abfederung hoher Arbeitslosigkeit auf Vancouver Island, Kanada.

Aber auch diese Sätze sind allesamt korrekt:

> - *Er* hatte den ersten LETS 1983 zur Bewältigung und Abfederung hoher Arbeitslosigkeit auf Vancouver Island, Kanada gegründet.
> - *Den ersten LETS* hatte er 1983 zur Bewältigung und Abfederung hoher Arbeitslosigkeit auf Vancouver Island, Kanada gegründet.
> - *1983* hatte er den ersten LETS zur Bewältigung und Abfederung hoher Arbeitslosigkeit auf Vancouver Island, Kanada gegründet.
> - *Zur Bewältigung und Abfederung hoher Arbeitslosigkeit* hatte er den ersten LETS 1983 auf Vancouver Island, Kanada gegründet.
> - *Auf Vancouver Island, Kanada* hatte er den ersten LETS 1983 zur Bewältigung und Abfederung hoher Arbeitslosigkeit gegründet.

Der bevorzugte Platz für das Partizip ist tatsächlich die letzte Position im Satz, aber wenn in der Verbklammer (hatte ... gegründet) so viele andere Satzteile stehen wie hier, ist es vorteilhaft, das Partizip ins Vorfeld zu stellen. Das erhöht die Verständlichkeit des Satzes.

Ein zweiter Grund um das Partizip nach vorne zu ziehen ist oft, dass man es besonders hervorheben will. Durch die ungewöhnliche (aber erlaubte) Position zieht das Wort mehr Aufmerksamkeit auf sich.

---

### 2. »da«

> ... Alternativgeld ... Freigeldtheorie ... Regionalgeld ...
>   Micheal Linton gilt **da** als Erfinder der Tauschring-Bewegung.

Das Adverb *»da«* bezieht sich auf den Kontext, der im Satz davor bereitgestellt wurde. Ursprünglich stellt *»da«* einen Bezug zur näheren räumlichen Umgebung des Sprechers dar:

> Ich melde mich aus Berlin. **Da** regnet es.

Aber die Verwendung im übertragenen Sinn (also ohne räumlichen Bezug) ist ebenso gängig:

> Heinz hat mir erzählt, dass er seinen alten Schrank abgeschliffen hat. **Da** muss es ganz schön gestaubt haben.

Hier ist mit *»da«* nicht der Ort der Handlung, sondern die Tätigkeit (das Abschleifen des Schrankes) gemeint. Und in deinem Beispiel bezieht sich *»da«* auch nicht auf einen Ort, sondern auf das Umfeld, das aus diversen alternativen Zahlungsmitteln besteht.

Natürlich wäre auch dieser Satz korrekt:

> Micheal Linton gilt als Erfinder der Tauschring-Bewegung.

Aber dann ist der Satz ein wenig abgetrennt vom vorangegangen Satz. Wenn man das *»da«* einfügt, stellt man einen stärkeren Bezug zum Kontext her.

---

### 3. *»auf«* statt *»im«*

Hier wäre *»im«* schichtweg falsch, und das sogar aus drei Gründen.

- **falsches Geschlecht**

  Das Wort *im* ist eine Verkürzung, die aus den Wörtern *»in« + »dem«* besteht. Und *»dem«* ist ein Artikel, der nur für männliche und sächliche Substantive verwendet werden kann:

  - männlich

    > der Wald
    >   Ich bin **im** Wald.
  - sächlich

    > das Meer
    >   Ich bin **im** Meer.
  - weiblich

    > die Stadt
    >   Ich bin **in der** Stadt.

  *»Die Insel«* ist weiblich, daher ist auch *Vancouver Island* weiblich, und mit dem richtigen Artikel würde man das erhalten:

  > Gegründet hatte er den ersten LETS 1983 ... **in der** Vancouver Island, Kanada.

  Aber auch das ist falsch.
- **falsche Präposition**

  Die Präposition *in* bedeutet, dass man sich im Inneren von etwas befindet. Wenn man im Inneren einer Insel ist, heißt das, dass man ein Loch gegraben hat, hinabgestiegen ist, und sich nun unterhalb der Erdoberfläche befindet. Herr Linton wird sich aber kaum unter die Erde begeben haben um die Tauschring-Bewegung zu gründen.

  Micheal Linton hat sich aber **auf** der Oberfläche der Insel aufgehalten als er die Bewegung gegründet hat. Also:

  > Gegründet hatte er den ersten LETS 1983 ... **auf der** Vancouver Island, Kanada.

  Aber auch das ist falsch.
- **überflüssiger Artikel**

  Da *Vancouver Island* ein geographischer Begriff ist, und die meisten geographischen Begriffe ohne Artikel verwendet werden, ist hier auch kein Artikel notwendig.

  Richtig ist also:

  > Gegründet hatte er den ersten LETS 1983 ... **auf** Vancouver Island, Kanada.

Comment: Danke Schön mein Lieblingslehrer

Comment: Das mit der *Oberfläche* ist noch ein bisschen abwegig. Ein Bergwerk *unter* einer Insel ist auch *auf* der Insel.

Comment: @tofro Das ist aber auch die einzige Schwachstelle in der Antwort. Ansonsten ist Sie glaube ich vollständig. Das "auf" ist dann doch sehr inselspezifisch. Wir würden z.B. "in der Lüneburger Heide" sagen. Für das Innere der Insel verwenden wir aber den Ausdruck "im Inneren der Insel". "In der Insel" wird gar nicht verwendet auch wenn man etwas unterirdisches beschreiben wollte.